# What's wrong with the logic in the following ''paradox''?

Tags: logic, paradox

The apparent paradox pertains to the homesteading principle. This isn't a question about the morality/immorality of homesteading, or ownership, or use, etc, just the logic behind it. The concept: everyone is allowed to use an unowned resource, then when you start using an unowned resource it becomes used and this allows you to claim exclusive ownership over it, but this turns an unowned resource into an excluded resource which violates the presupposition that everyone is allowed to use an unowned resource. By using an unowned resource you claim ownership over it which means you claim ownership over an originally-unused resource!

"Either you have the right to exclude others from unused property in which case you own it (since ownership means "the right to exclusive use") without having used it first, or you do not have the right to exclude others from unused property, in which case you cannot homestead, as that would be excluding others."

What's the issue here? It seems to me that the act of using is not taken into account completely and you cannot just use the transitive property like this.

Comment: You do not _have to_ claim ownership of a resource, you can move along and let it return to being unused.

Comment: Once you use something, it becomes used, not unused. You wouldn't offer to buy someone's ''unused'' sandals at the beach just because they're not wearing them anymore.

Comment: You should make a distinction between 'resources' and usable objects.

Comment: Makes me think of Russell's paradox and the  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barber_paradox

Comment: The Barber ''paradox'' is not a paradox since it's just a claim of said claim

Comment: This is just sort of generalizing Zeno's paradox relative to claiming.  There is some instant when you have 'used' something, but the instant before, you were not able to prevent it from being used by someone else.  So if you both want to claim it, neither of you can use it.   If you assume every resource is 'wanted', by virtue of deserving the label of resource, there is no way to make this transition.  But this is really just ignoring the existence of time on general principles, which is silly.  Time exists, people win races.

Comment: "So if you both want to claim it, neither of you can use it." This doesn't follow. It's impossible for two claimers to make a claim at the exact same moment. One claimant will make the claim, and that's that.

"If you assume every resource is 'wanted', by virtue of deserving the label of resource, there is no way to make this transition." Not every resources is wanted. You do not want resources you are ignorant of.

Answer (score 2):

You need to distinguish between exlcusive and non-exclusive right to use the resource. An example of a similar procedure in a different setting might illuminate this:

*A family has a basket of apples standing in the kitchen. Any familiar member is allowed to go there, take an apple and eat it. It is not allowed to wrestle an apple a person is currently eating from them, though.*

Here we have an non-exclusive right to eat the apples in the basket, which is transformed in an exclusive right as soon someone starts eating it. There is no a priori problem in the symmetry, except maybe in the case that two people want to transform the right into exclusive at the very same time.

Comment: How is that a non-exclusive right though when you have the right to exclude others from the apple?

Comment: Exclusive means that only you have the right to eat it, not that you can somehow obtain the exclusive right.